# Java average calculation

Tags: java, math

When I run the following code in java it does not give me the right average result who's supposed to be 97.5. Can anyone help me please.

```
//class
public class NumericTypes {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        final int NUMBER = 2 ; // number of scores
        final int SCORE1 = 100; // first test score
        final int SCORE2 = 95; // second test score
        final int BOILING_IN_F = 212; // freezing temperature
        int fToC; // temperature in Celsius
        double average; // arithmetic average
        String output; // line of output to print out

        // Find an arithmetic average
        average = (SCORE1 + SCORE2) / NUMBER;
        output = SCORE1 + " and " + SCORE2 + " have an average of " + average;
        System.out.println(output);

        // Convert Fahrenheit temperatures to Celsius
        fToC = (BOILING_IN_F - 32) * 5/9;
        output = BOILING_IN_F + " in Fahrenheit is " + fToC + " in Celsius.";
        System.out.println(output);
        System.out.println(); // to leave a blank line 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are performing integer math, cast one of the values to a `double` and you'll get the correct result.

```
average = ((double)(SCORE1 + SCORE2)) / NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this

```
final int NUMBER = 2 ;
```

to

```
final double NUMBER = 2 ;
```